# Docker File AWS

Tags: machine-learning, aws, sagemaker, amazon-ml

I am trying to implement a docker file for Amazon Sagemaker Container,in initial step i am following this link
https://towardsdatascience.com/brewing-up-custom-ml-models-on-aws-sagemaker-e09b64627722

In above link's section "Creating Your Own Docker Container" last command of docker image is

COPY xgboost /opt/program

I don't have any idea what xgboost file here is for this? Due to this my docker build is failing , please see below image of docker and its built
**Docker Image**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install numpy==1.19.5 scipy scikit-learn==0.23.2 pandas xgboost==1.5.0 flask gunicorn
# Set some environment variables. PYTHONUNBUFFERED keeps Python from buffering our standard
# output stream, which means that logs can be delivered to the user quickly. PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
# keeps Python from writing the .pyc files which are unnecessary in this case. We also update
# PATH so that the train and serve programs are found when the container is invoked.

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

# Set up the program in the image
COPY xgboost /opt/program

                           

    (base) khurram@khurram-ubuntu:~/Documents/images$ sudo docker build -t xgboost-tut .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> ba6acccedd29
Step 2/10 : MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 761e1c69837f
Step 3/10 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3b0df88fc501
Step 4/10 : RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f992ad04e00d
Step 5/10 : RUN pip --no-cache-dir install numpy==1.19.5 scipy scikit-learn==0.23.2 pandas xgboost==1.5.0 flask gunicorn
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 812ff132c4a0
Step 6/10 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d7ec66ab111c
Step 7/10 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 924ce5e83878
Step 8/10 : ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7ece4b08fe57
Step 9/10 : COPY xgboost /opt/program
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat xgboost: file does not exist
(base) khurram@khurram-ubuntu:~/Documents/images$
```